# Kubernetes HAProxy Ingress doesn't work without explicitly setting host header

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, kubectl

I followed the tutorial from https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-9r1/traffic-management/kubernetes-ingress-controller/ to setup the haproxy controller (community edition) and the "Echo Server" App that should be accessed.

When I run `curl -L -H 'Host: echo.example.com' localhost:30884` I get the desired response

```
Request served by app-58f7d69f54-p2kq8

HTTP/1.1 GET /

Host: echo.example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: 10.42.0.0
```

However if I just use `curl -L  echo.example.com:30884` I get the response `default backend - 404`
So apperently the request reaches the ingress controller, but the ingress controller doesn't know which host should be used.

Running `kubectl get ing` gives me

```
eignungstest              eignungstest.example.com          10.43.173.120   80      17h
kube-web-view             dashboard.example.com                             80      16h
web-ingress               echo.example.com                                  80      16h
```

it seems there is no address assigned, but running the same commands above with the host `eignungstest.example.com` I get the same results, so that should be of no relevance.

Is there a setting I'm missing that prevents the host header from being passed when I dont explicitly specify it?

Comment: Could you attach your ingress definition in yaml format ? Run `kubectl get ingress web-ingress -o yaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingress controller and ingress looks fine.

As you can see in your `kubectl` response the ingress is pointing to port 80 of that service which would pick up `echo.example.com`.

So it only knows about port 80 of echo.example.com, but when you try `curl -L echo.example.com:30884`, it is checking for that particular port and routing all the traffic to default backend.

Make sure you could directly `curl -L echo.example.com`, if it doesn't work check the service if the service has something similar.

```
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3001
```

You might have done the service part right as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: No the wiring of ports is all fine, because I can reach the services when settings the hostname explicit, 30884 is the nodeport of my ingress controller

Comment: I think now I see what you mean, I checked the Chrome Network Panel and the Host Header is literally `Host: echo.example.com:30884`, i'll expose the ingress on port 80 quickly and report if that solves the problem.

Comment: I installed an nginx reverse proxy on port 80 in front of the ingress and now it works.